# Usehealthchecks vs Maphealthchecks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, health-check

I've looked around from place to place but I am assuming one is an older way of doing things, but is there a more deeper difference to adding Health Check Endpoints to the middleware?

`In Startup.Configure()..`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
});
```

---

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/health")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`UseHealthChecks` and `MapHealthChecks` have subtle differences, `UseHealthChecks` allows you to capture any endpoint on a port when using null or empty PathString, `MapHealthChecks` does not allow this, using null throws an exception, and an empty string is just the equivalent of `/`.

They both use the same middleware `HealthCheckMiddleware` behind the scene.  The `MapHealthChecks` is an extension method on `IEndpointRouteBuilder`, whereas `UseHealthChecks` is an extension method on `IApplicationBuilder`.

Here is a reference to the source for reference.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Middleware/HealthChecks/src/Builder

If you look at the source you will see that `UseHealthChecks` uses `MapWhen()` where `MapHealthChecks` uses `Map()`