# why not use HealthCheckMiddleware explictly for Health Check?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

the norm of using Health Check is like the code below

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddHealthChecks()         
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc");
        });
    }
}
```

if we check the source code of `MapHealthChecks` https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/Builder/HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs,68

then we can see it calls `UseMiddleware<HealthCheckMiddleware>(args)`

so why it is not like traditional approach as below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddHealthChecks()         
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<HealthCheckMiddleware>("/hc")  // <---------this is what we normally do when add a middleware in the pipeline

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks();  // remove the call of UseMiddleware<HealthCheckMiddleware> in the implementation
        });
    }
}
```

also, `MapHealthChecks` calls

```
var pipeline = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder()
    .UseMiddleware<HealthCheckMiddleware>(args)
    .Build();
```

why it needs to create a new ApplicationBuilder? why not use existing ApplicationBuilder and add the middleware to the exsiting ApplicationBuilder? why the `HealthCheckMiddleware` needs to apply on a new ApplicationBuilder?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72384646/usehealthchecks-vs-maphealthchecks